# Jaspereports printing dialog in the server side

Tags: jsf, web-applications, jasper-reports

I developped a web application using JSF 
, i have a problem with printing reports using jasperreports.

when i try to print in the client side, the print dialog is showing up in the server side.

```
InputStream reportStream = ctx.getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/ressources/reports/DAreport.jasper");
JasperPrint fluxJasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportStream, parameters, connection);              
JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
  exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, fluxJasperPrint);
  exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
  exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.TRUE);
  exporter.exportReport();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the application is running server-sided, the print-dialouge is shown on the server.

Either run the app on client-side (if you have  a fat-client) or install a default printer on the server and print with default-settings, so that the dialog does not show up.